# query execution error check

Tags: php

hello please help me out regarding this function

```
  function delete($serviceid) 
    {
    $result = $this->query=("delete from service where service_id='$serviceid'");
    $exe=$this->executeNonQuery();
    if ($exe){
    return $success = "Record deleted successfully.";
    } else {
    return $error = "Unable to process at this time.";
    }
    }
```

$exe is always 1 even if the record is not deleted as may b its because of , it only check that query is executed or not , how can i check if the record is deleted then show success message

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is $this->query? Does it use builtin mysql functions? Are you using PDO? Are you using Mysqli?

Comment: The method name `executeNonQuery` seems to be used in database adapters for a few Microsoft technologies, FWIW.  I found one *horrible* example PHP database adapter in Google.  I hope that's not the one being used here.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if he was calling one of those adapters over COM, but then we would see a COM method...

Comment: @umar, you should really use something else... you aren't escaping your data.  This is horribly insecure.  Try PDO.  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: in the api its like this function executeNonQuery() //executes non queries
{
try
{
$check = $this->conn->query($this->query);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$this->error = "An Error Occurred, while executing a Non Query";
$this->edetail = $e->getMessage();
return false;
}
return true;
}

Comment: i have edit my question and put the Db class . please chaeck it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what DB class you are using, but there are generally separate methods for accessing the number of affected rows, and whether or not the command was 'successful' (only from the viewpoint of the DB interface).

Look for something in your API documentation for number of affected rows or something similar.

If you could post more details, we can give you a specific answer.

**EDIT:**  Now that we know you are using mysqli, you can use `mysql->affected_rows()` to get the number of rows deleted.  See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

```
function affectedRows() {
    return mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn);
}
```

Add that to your "Person" class.

And then, [switch to PDO and prepared statements](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).  What you are doing is very insecure.

Comment: The Api function looks like this function executeNonQuery() //executes non queries
{
try
{
$check = $this->conn->query($this->query);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$this->error = "An Error Occurred, while executing a Non Query";
$this->edetail = $e->getMessage();
return false;
}
return true;
}

Comment: @umar, that isn't helpful.  What DB layer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

check for `mysql_affected_rows()`

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: if u r using any class for mysql then there must be a function to check the  The number of rows in a result set on success .  u shoud try that.

Comment: This won't work, as he isn't using `mysql_query()`, so he doesn't have a valid resource to pass to `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: for a delete you should use mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected.

Answer (score 1):

We definitely need more information on the class that $this is an instance of in order to know how it's query functions work.  However, if that class is using a mysql connection, the mysql_affected_rows() function should return the number of rows that were deleted.

A quick test would be to substitute that function instead of checking the value of $exe:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows()){
   return $success = "Record deleted successfully.";
}
```

Check this out for more details: https://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows